# Add variable to form action in Laravel Vue Component

Tags: laravel, vue.js

How can I add a variable to the form action in Laravel Vue Component?

```
<form method="POST" action="/thoughtjournal/{{id}}/update">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you might want to use Vue models and Axios to submit your form from Vue. It's kind of one of the magical parts of working with Vue.

However, to answer your question you need to bind the action attribute using js, so you need to create a variable in the Vue's data array of id and then use the following:

`<form method="POST" :action="'/thoughtjournal/' + id + '/update'">`

Again, tough, that is very much not how you should be working in vue.  Instead you should use v-model biding to build up/edit the thought journal model, then post or patch it using axios.